Matplotlib venn3 empty subgroup layout
I'm creating a venn3 diagram using matplotlib_venn where one of the subsets is empty. Minimal example -
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles

group1 = set([1,2, 3])
group2 = set([1, 4, 5])
group3 = set([4, 5])
venn3(subsets = [group1, group2, group3], set_labels = ['a','b' ,'c'])
plt.show()

And I get the following image -

The empty subset appears in the image, although I wouldn't like it to appear (i.e., the layout should be improved; I can remove the labels later). What can I do to improve the layout?
(I tried a few cost algorithms, but nothing helped)

The cost-based layout does not let you change the relative sizes of the circles, which makes it hard for the layout to fit the circle C inside of circle B. What you need to do to help the algorithm is to artifically increase the size of the B circle with respect to C. For example, by simply adding some elements to the B/C set:
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles

group1 = set([1, 2, 3])
group2 = set([1, 4, 5] + [10, 11])
group3 = set([4, 5])

v = venn3([group1, group2, group3])
v.get_label_by_id("010").set_visible(False)

This results in circles A and B being of very different sizes which is, IMO, a rather misleading representation of the data:

A perhaps slightly better way of squeezing the circle C completely inside B is by:

Moving A out (by reducing the intersection A&B artificially)
Reducing the size of C to fit.

Something like that:
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
from matplotlib_venn.layout.venn3 import DefaultLayoutAlgorithm

group1 = set([1, 2, 3])
group2 = set([1, 4, 5])
group3 = set([4, 5])

sizes=[len(group1 - group2 - group3),
       len(group2 - group1 - group3),
       len((group1 & group2) - group3),
       len(group3 - group1 - group2),
       len(group3 & group1 - group2),
       len(group3 & group2 - group1),
       len(group1 & group2 & group3)]

# Reduce the A&B intersection size
sizes[0b011-1] *= 0.3
# Move some of the mass from B&C into B/C
sizes[0b110-1] -= 0.6
sizes[0b010-1] += 0.6
venn3(subsets = [group1, group2, group3],
      layout_algorithm=DefaultLayoutAlgorithm(fixed_subset_sizes=sizes))


The two sacrifices made here are:

C is not 2/3 of the size of B anymore.
A&B intersection is not 1/3 of either's area.

Whether it is acceptable or not is up to you to decide, and I suspect the original data is different. In any case, this exercise should illustrate the inherent limitations of Venn circles.
